# Selenium WaitForElement in c# throws ElementNotVisibleException

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
IWebDriver driver = Browser.Instance.Driver;

if (timeout > 0)
{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout));
    try
    {
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(selector));
        return driver.FindElement(selector);
    }
    catch(NoSuchElementException)
    {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
}
else
{
    // Search for element without timeout 
    return driver.FindElement(selector);
}
```

This is my code and i really don't know why it is throwing an Exception here. My timout is set to 30 seconds but he throws the Exception after a couple seconds already. When i run the Test in Debug Modus and wait for the Element myself, it works fine.

At first I used this, but didn't work either

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds));
return wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(by));</code>
```

Comment: Catching `NoSuchElementException` and throwing a new instance of it again. ...Just why..? Not only it doesn't makes sense, but it destroys the stack trace too.

Comment: Not really a productive message, why not tell me how to make it better instead of throwing in a "thats stupid" message?

Comment: Simply don't catch it. That's exactly equivalent to what you have now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ExpectedConditions.ElementExists();` is waiting for the element to *exists* in the DOM . To make sure the element is *visible* in the website use `ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible()`

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(selector));
```

As a side not, if `wait.Until` condition doesn't met it throws `WebDriverTimeoutException`, not `NoSuchElementException`.

Comment: Thanks for the info, included it and it works.

The NoSuchElementException never gets thrown? Or just not if the wait condition takes longer than the timeout?